# What is the voltage at a node between two series voltage sources?

Tags: voltage

Hopefully the title explains it. As an example, what is the voltage at node one in the schematic below? And more importantly, why? I believe the answer is 0V, but I suppose what I'm thinking is: Why isn't it 125V? Thanks for any help you can give.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fEBbNE.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Gorlath, you are a champion. It wouldn't let me put it in there because I don't have enough points.

Comment: Voltage relative to what?  There can be no answer without a reference to measure in comparison to.  It's unclear, but someone may have drawn a variety of ground symbol there, and if that was the intent it would make this the implicit reference point for measuring other voltages, and thus 0 relative to itself.

Comment: @Joseph Rocca Are those **120V AC**?

Comment: DC. Thanks guys. All makes so much more sense now :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To say the "voltage at" is incorrect. Voltage is a difference.

When people say the voltage at a point, what they really mean is the voltage from said point to ground.

Because there is a ground symbol next to your node with nothing in between you can say that the voltage from the node to ground is zero.

see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage

Comment: Ahh! Thanks so much. So for the node underneath the bottom voltage source: is that node at a voltage of -125V relative to ground?

Comment: @JosephRocca, Yep!

Comment: Brilliant! It's all starting to make sense. Thanks.